# What is the right amount of space to place between a quantor and the following expression?

Tags: math-mode, spacing

Given a formula with a quantor like this:

```
$\exists x\in S. p(x)$
```

TeX does not place space between `.` and `p` by default. What is the correct amount of space to use in this case?

Comment: May I ask where that notation (a dot instead of a colon) is used? If you found that in publications, I'd recommend you try using a similar spacing as they have.

Comment: @magula That's a fairly common notation in Logic. In fact, I've never seen a colon being used there.

Comment: To be honest, I'm used to no separating symbol at all (_especially_ in logic), whereas in other contexts one often finds a colon. I _think_ I only remember having seen a dot used like that in a "computational" context (I've seen it _somewhere_, maybe I just remember it incorrectly) -- but I'm not a logician, and maybe it depends on who you learn from. Just curious. ;)

Comment: The period becomes more or less necessary once you start to use typed qualifiers. Both `\forall x\in S. p(x)` and `\forall x:T. p(x)` desperately want that period as you otherwise have trouble parsing what is actually going on. Without a type or set, just some space does it, but since both the colon and the element operator are surrounded by space on their own, it get's really hard to read without an explicit separator.

Comment: Surprisingly, Ellen Swanson’s _Mathematics into Type_ dosen’t seem to cover this case.  I could find a single example, on p. 44, which suggests something along the lines of `(\exists x\in S)p(x)`, whitout any space—which I find ugly!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe `\ldotp` can be used for this purpose. The code `$\exists x\in S\ldotp p(x)$` will produce the desired output.

[image]

Comment: Good point (+1)!  But could you cite a normative reference that endorses this?

Comment: Sorry @GuM, I can't. I sense there is no agreement on what is considered standard. But I've learned it's best not to get into an argument with logicians about notation. Some are fiercely attached to what they consider correct. I've seen the dot notation used in [Lambda Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#The_lambda_calculus), usually with the trailing space.  Some computer scientists seem to favor it, but are inconsistent with spacing. Some prefer commas; some strongly oppose commas used in this way. I'm a topologist—we don't have consistent notation for anything!